# Telegram, notification sound

Tags: android, ios, windows, bots, telegram

how to make the telegram's sound notification like an alarm, so that whenever there is a new post in the channel the phone keeps beeping like an alarm.

One possible solution on the iOS would be to forward messages from the channel (that's not mine, but I am a member) to my phone via SMS, as you can set a constant alarm for SMSes on iPhone.

I do not really have any better ideas on how to do this, so I am open to any clues that you can come up with. Maybe some of you know if there is any other way to achieve the same result on ios, android, windows phone or computer.

Thanks

Comment: It's impossible since Telegram didn't provide this feature

Answer (score 4):

To set a **custom notification sound for any app**, do as follows:

**Settings** : **General** : **Apps & Notifications** : **App info**

Now scroll to the app that you want to customise.  In this case, select Telegram by pressing it.

Select "**App notifications**".  Now you can select a default notification, but more particularly, you can pick a group or contact from the list.

The default setting for importance is "**medium: no sound**".  Press that and change it to "**Urgent**" or "**High**".  Go back one screen.  Now you can select the sound, by pressing "**Sound**".  Pick a sound, or add a custom sound by pressing "**+**" at the top right.

If you want to record something, like a voicetag that says "Telegram from Tom", simply move a recording of that into the "music" folder on your phone, select it as above and when a message comes in from Tom, you'll hear the message played.

*These steps were taken on Android 8 on an LG G6, but should be similar for other phones.  For older versions of Android this feature may not be available.  IOS?  Sorry, none around here.*

You can also do this in the Telegram app:  Screenshots below.

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]
[image: Step3]
[image: Step4]
[image: Step5]

Comment: Thank you @Lifeboy , but adding "Custom sound" doesn't seem to be an option in my android 10

Answer (score 0):

The channel members would need to set a specific alarm sound for the channel. There is no way the sender of a message (not even a bot) could modify the sound of a notification.